# Split string and append parts in running list [Python]

Tags: python, split, line-breaks

I have a veery long list that contains the same pattern. Here an original example:

```
04:50 10 244.685 0 0
05:00 10 244.680 0 0
HBCHa 9990 Seite 762
16.02.16
Hafenpegel 
Pegel müM Var 0 Pegelstand
Datum Zeit Intervall müM Q Art
Sonntag, 31. Dezember 2000 05:10 10 244.679 0 0
05:20 10 244.688 0 0
05:30 10 244.694 0 0
05:40 10 244.688 0 0
```

As you can see, there is one line with measurement-data within the string that starts with "Sonntag"

My target is:

```
04:50 10 244.685 0 0
05:00 10 244.680 0 0
HBCHa 9990 Seite 762
16.02.16
Hafenpegel 
Pegel müM Var 0 Pegelstand
Datum Zeit Intervall müM Q Art
Sonntag, 31. Dezember 2000 
05:10 10 244.679 0 0            !!
05:20 10 244.688 0 0
05:30 10 244.694 0 0
05:40 10 244.688 0 0
```

I managed to write the txt-file in a list, here called "data_list_splitted", catch this onle line over the whole txt-file, split it and extract the part with the measurements:

```
for i in data_list_splitted:

if len(i) >= 40:

    ii = i.split(";")


    txt_line = "%s;%s;%s;%s;%s"%(ii[4],ii[5],ii[6],ii[7],ii[8])
```

But i don't get it to break this line and add the measurement-values in the running list!

I think this should't be that difficult?
Any ideas?
Thank you very much!

Comment: why split on `;`?  Try to instead write `ii = i.split()`. If that doesn't work, try providing the output of `ii` and/or any error message received.

Comment: every element in the data_list_splitted is splitted by ";". I don't work with the original file. Spaces were replaced with ;

Comment: So you mean `Sonntag, 31. Dezember 2000 05:10 10 244.679 0 0` is actually `Sonntag,;31.;Dezember;2000;05:10;10;244.679;0;0`? Also, could you edit the question to provide an example of how you want the output?

Comment: in data_list_splitted, yes ;-)

Comment: So, as far as i understand, you want *all* the measurement data, but you can't get the measurement which comes after a date. And you want all this as strings back in the list `data_list_splitted` . Before you opened the file, it is full of semicolons, and you want your `data_list_splitted` to stay full of semicolon strings of measurements. Correct? and do you want to *replace* the list string for that line, or *insert* it as a new value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create another list and insert values into it

```
new_data_list_splitted = []
for i in data_list_splitted:
  if len(i) >= 40:
    ii = i.split(";")
    txt_line = "%s;%s;%s;%s;%s"%(ii[0],ii[1],ii[2],ii[3],ii[4])
    new_data_list_splitted.append(txt_line)
    txt_line = "%s;%s;%s;%s;%s"%(ii[4],ii[5],ii[6],ii[7],ii[8])
    new_data_list_splitted.append(txt_line)
  else:
    new_data_list_splitted.append(i)

print new_data_list_splitted #this will have a new row for measurement value
```

Comment: this is easy and exactly what i wanted!